# C Programm with with duplicate values in a three-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c

I have written a C program in which I output the lowest and highest temperature with day of the week and time in the lower function. However, sometimes values are duplicated. How can I implement this in my function so that both times are displayed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

double week_statistics(double array[52][7][24], int kalenderwoche, int j, int i, int k, int daymin, int hourmin, int daymax, int hourmax){

  double min = array[0][0][0];

    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < 24; k++){
      if(array[i][j][k] < min){
            min = array[i][j][k];
            daymin = j + 1;
            hourmin = k + 1;

        }}}

printf("Die niedrigste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %d. Wochentag um %d Uhr.\n", min, kalenderwoche, daymin, hourmin);

 double max = array[0][0][0];    

    for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < 24; k++){

        if(array[i][j][k] > max){
            max = array[i][j][k];
            daymax = j + 1;
            hourmax = k + 1;

        }}}}

printf("Die höchste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %d. Wochentag um %d Uhr.\n", max, kalenderwoche, daymax, hourmax);  
}


int main(){

  double array[52][7][24] = {{

            {9.6,  9.4, 9.3, 9.1, 7.9, 7.7, 7.3, 7.2, 8.8, 9.3, 9.7, 9.4, 10.2, 9.7, 9.9, 9.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.2, 7.1, 6.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.2},
            {4.9, 4.6, 4.6, 4.1, 3.5, 3.1, 2.6, 2.6, 3.5, 5.1, 6.2, 8.3, 9.0, 9.3, 9.1, 8.0, 6.8, 6.4, 5.4, 5.2, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5},
            {6.3, 6.8, 7.0, 7.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.1, 7.4, 7.7, 8.2, 8.7, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.6, 8.4, 8.0, 7.9, 7.7, 7.6, 7.5, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2},
            {7.1, 7.0, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.2, 7.5, 7.7, 8.1, 8.3, 8.0, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 7.7, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9},
            {8.1, 8.0, 7.9, 7.8, 7.5, 7.2, 6.9, 7.2, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 8.7, 8.9, 9.0, 7.8, 8.5, 8.1, 7.7, 7.7, 6.7, 7.0, 6.5, 7.1},
            {6.4, 6.6, 6.3, 5.8, 5.0, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9, 5.3, 6.1, 5.5, 5.3, 5.7, 5.8, 6.5, 6.6, 5.8, 5.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.3, 5.8},
            {4.4, 4.0, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3.8, 4.4, 5.2, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1, 6.7, 6.3, 5.9, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.7, 7.2, 7.7}

                               }};
 
  int kalenderwoche = 45;
  int i, j,k;
  int daymin,daymax = 1;
  int hourmin,hourmax = 1;

  week_statistics(array, kalenderwoche, i, j ,k, daymin, hourmin, daymax, hourmax); //c)

  
  }
```

Comment: No, is not given in the task

Comment: You should use local variables in `week_statistics` instead of passing all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In C programming for storing the values that you don't have their count without using any third party libraries, you have two main approaches. One way is to create an very large array and store your data into it, by using this approach you must have an upper bound for your number of inputs. Another way is using dynamic memory allocation. There are multiple ways for using dynamic memory allocation and one the simplest approach is using [`realloc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/realloc.3) and increasing a dynamically allocated memory one by one (this solution is simple for implementation and may not good enough for memory/time consumption).

First approach:

```c
int daymin[100] = {0};
int dayminindex = 0;

...

    daymin[dayminindex] = j + 1;
    dayminindex++;
```

and the second approach is:

```c
int *daymin = NULL;
int dayminlen = 0;

...

    dayminlen++;
    daymin = realloc(daymin, len * sizeof(int));
    daymin[dayminlen - 1] = j + 1;
```

After applying the second approach in your code, we will have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>



double week_statistics(double array[52][7][24], int kalenderwoche){
  int i, j, k;

  int minlen = 0;
  int *daymin = NULL;
  int *hourmin = NULL;

  double min = array[0][0][0];

  for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < 24; k++){
        if(array[i][j][k] < min) {
          min = array[i][j][k];

          minlen = 0;
          free(daymin);
          free(hourmin);
          daymin = NULL;
          hourmin = NULL;
        }
        // here we will add the first one
        if(array[i][j][k] == min) {
          minlen++;

          daymin = realloc(daymin, minlen * sizeof(int));
          daymin[minlen - 1] = j + 1;

          hourmin = realloc(hourmin, minlen * sizeof(int));
          hourmin[minlen - 1] = k + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < minlen; i++) {
    printf("Die niedrigste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %d. Wochentag um %d Uhr.\n", min, kalenderwoche, daymin[i], hourmin[i]);
  }

  int maxlen = 0;
  int *daymax = NULL;
  int *hourmax = NULL;

  double max = array[0][0][0];

  for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < 24; k++){
        if(array[i][j][k] > max){
          max = array[i][j][k];

          maxlen = 0;
          free(daymax);
          free(hourmax);
          daymax = NULL;
          hourmax = NULL;
        }
        // here we will add the first one
        if(array[i][j][k] == max){
          maxlen++;

          daymax = realloc(daymax, maxlen * sizeof(int));
          daymax[maxlen - 1] = j + 1;

          hourmax = realloc(hourmax, maxlen * sizeof(int));
          hourmax[maxlen - 1] = k + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
    printf("Die höchste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %d. Wochentag um %d Uhr.\n", max, kalenderwoche, daymax[i], hourmax[i]);
  }
}


int main(){

  double array[52][7][24] = {
    {
      {9.6,  9.4, 9.3, 9.1, 7.9, 7.7, 7.3, 7.2, 8.8, 9.3, 9.7, 9.4, 10.2, 9.7, 9.9, 9.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.2, 7.1, 6.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.2},
      {4.9, 4.6, 4.6, 4.1, 3.5, 3.1, 2.6, 2.6, 3.5, 5.1, 6.2, 8.3, 9.0, 9.3, 9.1, 8.0, 6.8, 6.4, 5.4, 5.2, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5},
      {6.3, 6.8, 7.0, 7.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.1, 7.4, 7.7, 8.2, 8.7, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.6, 8.4, 8.0, 7.9, 7.7, 7.6, 7.5, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2},
      {7.1, 7.0, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.2, 7.5, 7.7, 8.1, 8.3, 8.0, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 7.7, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9},
      {8.1, 8.0, 7.9, 7.8, 7.5, 7.2, 6.9, 7.2, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 8.7, 8.9, 9.0, 7.8, 8.5, 8.1, 7.7, 7.7, 6.7, 7.0, 6.5, 7.1},
      {6.4, 6.6, 6.3, 5.8, 5.0, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9, 5.3, 6.1, 5.5, 5.3, 5.7, 5.8, 6.5, 6.6, 5.8, 5.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.3, 5.8},
      {4.4, 4.0, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3.8, 4.4, 5.2, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1, 6.7, 6.3, 5.9, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.7, 7.2, 7.7}
    }
  };

  int kalenderwoche = 45;

  week_statistics(array, kalenderwoche);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but honestly I dont really understand how to implement it in my code:D

Comment: I can write it down with your code in answer, let me do this

Comment: That would be great;)

Comment: Thank you so much! But there is an error code...

Comment: Can you please send the error code here?

Comment: Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffde8729acf in ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Comment: Have you tested the code yourself? For the lowest temperature value the program now prints countless times

Comment: I ran it, seems good to me because all of those temperatures were zero. You said that your input data has 52 rows (52 x 7 x 24) and you only specify the first row, so all other rows will be initialized to zero and because of that you will have many zeros. You can remove the first loop over 52 rows and only use first row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third approach that sometimes preferable when you have a stream of values and you just care about the statistics, not the individual values. (As you seem to have here.) You can take the data on-line in a single pass, only updating the values you care about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct measure {
    size_t count;
    /* On-line numerically stable first-order, <Welford, 1962, Note>. */
    double mean, ssdm;
    struct { double min, max; } value;
    struct { size_t min, max; } arg_hour, arg_day;
};
static void m_add(struct measure *const m, const double replica,
    const size_t hour, const size_t day) {
    const size_t n = ++m->count;
    const double delta = replica - m->mean;
    m->mean += delta / n;
    m->ssdm += delta * (replica - m->mean);
    if(n == 1 || replica < m->arg_hour.min) m->arg_hour.min = hour; /* argmin */
    if(n == 1 || replica > m->arg_hour.max) m->arg_hour.max = hour; /* argmax */
    if(n == 1 || replica < m->arg_day.min) m->arg_day.min = day; /* argmin */
    if(n == 1 || replica > m->arg_day.max) m->arg_day.max = day; /* argmax */
    if(n == 1 || replica < m->value.min) m->value.min = replica;
    if(n == 1 || replica > m->value.max) m->value.max = replica;
}
static double m_mean(const struct measure *const m)
    { return m->count ? m->mean : 0. / 0.; }
static double m_sample_variance(const struct measure *const m)
    { return m->count > 1 ? m->ssdm / (m->count - 1) : 0. / 0.; }
static double m_stddev(const struct measure *const m)
    { return sqrt(m_sample_variance(m)); }

int main(void) {
    double array[][7][24] = {
        {
            { 9.6,  9.4, 9.3, 9.1, 7.9, 7.7, 7.3, 7.2, 8.8, 9.3, 9.7, 9.4,
                10.2, 9.7, 9.9, 9.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.2, 7.1, 6.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.2 },
            { 4.9, 4.6, 4.6, 4.1, 3.5, 3.1, 2.6, 2.6, 3.5, 5.1, 6.2, 8.3, 9.0,
                9.3, 9.1, 8.0, 6.8, 6.4, 5.4, 5.2, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5 },
            { 6.3, 6.8, 7.0, 7.2, 7.1, 7.2, 7.1, 7.4, 7.7, 8.2, 8.7, 9.1, 8.8,
                8.7, 8.6, 8.4, 8.0, 7.9, 7.7, 7.6, 7.5, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2 },
            { 7.1, 7.0, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.2, 7.5,
                7.7, 8.1, 8.3, 8.0, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 7.7, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9},
            { 8.1, 8.0, 7.9, 7.8, 7.5, 7.2, 6.9, 7.2, 8.0, 8.4, 8.7, 9.0, 8.7,
                8.9, 9.0, 7.8, 8.5, 8.1, 7.7, 7.7, 6.7, 7.0, 6.5, 7.1},
            { 6.4, 6.6, 6.3, 5.8, 5.0, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9, 5.3, 6.1, 5.5, 5.3,
                5.7, 5.8, 6.5, 6.6, 5.8, 5.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.3, 5.8},
            { 4.4, 4.0, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3.8, 4.4, 5.2, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1,
                6.7, 6.3, 5.9, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.7, 7.2, 7.7 }
        }
    };
    const int kalenderwoche = 45;
    size_t j, k;
    struct measure m = { 0 };
    for(j = 0; j < sizeof *array / sizeof **array; j++) {
        for(k = 0; k < sizeof **array / sizeof ***array; k++) {
            m_add(&m, array[0][j][k], k + 1, j + 1);
        }
    }
    printf("Die niedrigste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %zu. Wochentag um %zu Uhr.\n"
        "Die höchste Temperatur war %lf° in der %d. Kalenderwoche am %zu. Wochentag um %zu Uhr.\n"
        "Mean %f +/- %1.1f.\n",
        m.value.min, kalenderwoche, m.arg_day.min, m.arg_hour.min,
        m.value.max, kalenderwoche, m.arg_day.max, m.arg_hour.max,
        m_mean(&m), m_stddev(&m));
}
```

I've also calculated the mean and standard-deviation using numerically-stable [Welford's on-line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm) using `mean` and `ssdm`, if you care about this.